# Calculated values using Angular FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm attempting to calculate a total or other value based on a particular value in a FormArray.

I'm finding that when subscribing to `valueChanges` and attempting to pass the whole array to something like `reduce`, the "new value" isn't present on the parent FormGroup.

[Original Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-reactiveform-total-original)

Sample:

```
this.frm.get('arr')['controls'][i].valueChanges
  .subscribe((newVal) => {
    this.frm.get('total').patchValue(
      this.frm.get('arr').value.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return acc + curr.v;
      }, 0)
    )
  });
```

If `arr` has values `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and I change the first value to `1`, I still get `10` instead of `11`.

`this.frm.get('arr').value` shows all the initial values and not the updated values.

I'm fairly new to Reactive Forms so I'm sure I'm just missing something fundamental here.

**UPDATE** (Have a solution, but I'm still lacking understanding):

I'd really love to know why I'm not able to subscribe to changes to the whole array like Eliseo had suggested.

I'm also interested in why there is such a difference between where I use `.value` - If the whole point of Reactive Forms are to be Model Driven and then pass `frm.value` to your Submit function, then why is `.value` so inconsistent throughout the form hierarchy?

**UPDATE 2**

[Updated StackBlitz Solution with guidance from Eliseo after his update](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-reactiveform-total?file=app/app.component.ts)

I've found a solution that I feel pretty good about. It doesn't use `controls` anywhere and feels very clean. Eliseo's suggested approach pushed me to try this out. I believe the important thing is casting to a `FormArray` and executing any `push` on that. This keeps the `parent` field tied to the rest of your `FormGroup` or `FormArray` thus it stays included in the `valueChanges` event.

I now believe using `controls` is an anti-pattern to Angular Reactive Forms, but I need to search for more guidance on that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not listen changes of all array and make total with newValues?

```
 //NOT ['controls'][i]
this.frm.get('arr')['controls'].valueChanges
  .subscribe((newVal) => {
    this.frm.get('total').patchValue(
      //use newVal
      newVal.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return acc + curr.v;
      }, 0)
    )
  });
```

That's not work, Change the code of buildForm for this:

```
buildForm() {
    let controls:any[]=[];
    for (let i:number = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      controls.push(this.builder.group({
        v: i
      }))
    this.frm = this.builder.group({
      total: [{value: '', disabled: true}],
      arr: this.builder.array(controls)
    });
      this.frm.get('arr').valueChanges
      .subscribe((newVal) => {
        let total:number=0;
        newVal.forEach(e=>{
          total=total+parseInt(e.v)});

        this.frm.get('total').patchValue(total,0)

      });
    }
  }
```

The main changes is use forEach and not reduce, the use of parseInt, and the way to make the formArray.

Comment: @McTalian, I don't know how your form is formated, perhaps is this.frm.get('arr').valuesChanges. Another thing, remember write the valuesChange after make the form

Comment: I have a StackBlitz above that shows the HTML, TS, and Angular ecosystem. Can you take a look and tell me if I'm doing something wrong there?

Comment: Your update works and feels a bit cleaner. I got it working with reduce again- I'm going to add an "add new row" button and test that. If that works, this will work very well for me. Thanks for taking the time to update!

Answer (score 4):

I got this to work.

```
this.frm.get('arr')['controls'][i].valueChanges
  .subscribe((newVal) => {
    this.frm.get('total').patchValue(
      this.frm.get('arr').value.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return acc + curr.v;
      }, 0) + (+newVal.v)
    )
  });
```

Something about your form is a little strange. All 5 controls bind to the same `formControlName` "v". I think that may be the reason this form isn't acting the way you would like. The above does work, but adding the `newVal` on the end like this just seems odd.

UPDATE:

This is working for all field changes.

```
this.frm.get('arr')['controls'][i].valueChanges
  .subscribe((newVal) => {
      const arr = <FormArray>this.frm.controls['arr'];
      let total = 0;
      arr.controls.forEach((c: any) => {
        console.log(c.value);
        total+= +c.value.v;
      });
      console.log('total',total);
      this.frm.get('total').patchValue(total)
  });
```

Not the prettiest code I have ever seen, but it works. Get rid of the console logs, and it may be something you can live with. :)

Comment: How would I have a FormArray that didn't bind to the same formControlName? Not sure I'm following.

Comment: I am not real sure. I tried playing around with it a little in the StackBlitz, but I couldn't come up with a good answer on that. I may play with it more. Maybe it isn't a real issue if this is what you need.

Comment: I'll give it a shot in the real world scenario tomorrow. I'm with you, though, the newVal addition seems odd but I'll try it!

Comment: Trying the `newVal` on the end in StackBlitz example only works if you change one field. If you try to change any other fields as well, the previous new values don't stick :(

Comment: Dang it! I guess that makes the answer not a good answer at all. I thought I was on to something. Sorry about that.

Comment: That does work, I brought back `reduce` instead of `forEach` and it seemed to have worked.
I'd love to understand why `.value` doesn't work at the array level, but it works at the control level. It seems there are multiple ways to do something but each works slightly differently and I think it's something I am doing wrong.