# change automatic total when change quantity or price and total post empty in ws

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have 2 problems in my form, but I don't understand for what.

1. I want to change automatic my total

> ```
>   <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
>           <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>
>           <input readonly formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" [(ngModel)]="variable" class="validate" [value]="total">
>         </div>
> ```

when I change quantity or price,

2. In this form, when I submit my all form, total goes empty in ws, when I input something the value go to ws. I don't want to change value, I want to got immediately in ws. I used readonly input, but don't change nothing

My html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="addsale" (ngSubmit)="onaddsale()">
  <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr style="color:black;">
        <th>Product_type_id</th>
        <th>product_id</th>
        <th>Unit_price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products; let i = index">
        <td>{{item.Product_type_id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.product_id}}</td>
        <td>
          <input formControlName="Unit_price" id="Unit_price" type="number" class="validate" [value]="item.Unit_price"> </td>
        <td>
          <input formControlName="Quantity" id="Quantity " type="number" class="validate" [value]="item.Quantity">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input readonly formControlName="Subtotal" id="Subtotal" type="number" class="validate" [value]="item.Unit_price*item.Quantity">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <label for="total">Total {{total}} ALL</label>
      <input readonly formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" [(ngModel)]="variable" class="validate" [value]="total">
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
      <label for="amount_paid">Amount Paid:</label>
      <input formControlName="amount_paid" id="amount_paid" [value]="total" type="text" class="validate">
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <div id="add_homebox_button_container" class="row" style="float: right;">
    <button id="add_client_button" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
      Register
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you should be using `ngModel` for thaty instead of `[value]`

Comment: You structure is complicated, having your typescript code would help. Otheriwise, what I can tell you is that you need to use form arrays.

Comment: formControlName is for Reactive Forms, [value] and [ngModel] is for template driven Form. NOT mix. If you want to see a "problem" like your using ReactiveForm see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019672/calculated-values-using-angular-formarray/49025435#49025435

Comment: I have  one sale and one array Products inside sale. In this code, total and amount_paid are in sale, not in array. All my value in Product, like Product_type_id,product_id,Unit_price,Quantity,Subtotal post value in my ws, total and amount_paid post empty.

Comment: remove model and value attributes. <input readonly formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" class="validate" >  Count your total: addsale.value.total=...